# Recursively list all files in directory (Unix)

Tags: python, unix, recursion

I am trying to list all files a directory recursively using python. I saw many solutions using `os.walk`. But I don't want to use `os.walk`. Instead I want to implement recursion myself.

```
import os
fi = []
def files(a):
        f =  [i for i in os.listdir(a) if os.path.isfile(i)]
        if len(os.listdir(a)) == 0:
                return
        if len(f) > 0:
                fi.extend(f)
        for j in [i for i in os.listdir(a) if os.path.isdir(i)]:
                files(j)


files('.')
print fi
```

I am trying to learn recursion. I saw following Q?A, but I am not able to implement correctly it in my code.

- [Python recursive directory reading without os.walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468294/python-recursive-directory-reading-without-os-walk)

Comment: If you want to but can't, perhaps revisit the choice to not use `os.walk()` instead.

Comment: @tripleee _"I am trying to learn recursion"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir` return only the filename (without the full path)
so I think calling `files(j)` will not work correctly.
try using `files(os.path.join(dirName,j))`

or something like this:

```
def files(a):
    entries =  [os.path.join(a,i) for i in os.listdir(a)]

    f =  [i for i in entries if os.path.isfile(i)]
    if len(os.listdir(a)) == 0:
            return
    if len(f) > 0:
            fi.extend(f)
    for j in [i for i in entries if os.path.isdir(i)]:
            files(j)
```

I tried to stay close to your structure. However, I would write it with only one loop over the entries, something like that:

```
def files(a):
    entries =  [os.path.join(a,i) for i in os.listdir(a)]
    if len(entries) == 0:
            return

    for e in entries:
        if os.path.isfile(e):
            fi.append(e)

        elif os.path.isdir(e):
            files(e)
```

Comment: (I would write it with only one loop over the listdir but i try to write close to your structure)

Comment: _I would write it with only one loop over the listdir but i try to write close to your structure_. What you mean by that. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: got it. Thanks for the cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is not to use a global variable. This can be done using the following. Just modified the previous answer a little bit. I think this might be a little more readable ...

```
def files(a):

    entries =  [os.path.join(a,i) for i in os.listdir(a)]

    folders     = filter(os.path.isdir,  entries)
    normalFiles = filter(os.path.isfile, entries)

    for f in folders: 
        normalFiles += files(f)

    return normalFiles
```